# How to select elements from 2 differents columns with a common word

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have 2 different columns in the same table, and I want to select lines which contain the word "Hello".

For the first column, I'm using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE column1 LIKE '%Hello%';
```

So what statement can I do to select everything in both columns?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, because it's no easy to understand what you mean

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%Hello%' OR column2 LIKE '%Hello%';
```

If you mean that you want both columns to have "hello" in:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%Hello%' AND column2 LIKE '%Hello%';
```

Comment: No problem; for future database questions you want to ask, it would be good to include an example of the data you have right now, and the result you want to produce from that data. If someone answers your question on SO, you should click the grey tick/check mark on the answer you used, so it turns green- this means other people can know from the dashboard that the question is answered. You can also click the up arrow to mark one or more answers as useful. Many answers can be marked as useful, including the one you accept, but only one answer can be marked as the accepted one you used